# C# Cannot resize control due to the error Type '...' is not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, serialization

I'm developing a C# winforms app with multiple assemblies. I've started getting an error that I can't get around.

Error message: Type 'AppData.Globals' in Assembly 'AppData, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture-neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

Caused when: trying to resize a UserControl (of type DateTimeExpEditor) that it used inside another user control (of type CtrlTypePropsEditorDateBox), both within assembly AppData. Oddly I can resize it by directly editing the Width property in the UserControl's property grid entry.

I am not trying to serialize anything (in fact, I did need to and went down the road of writing my own serializer method, which works fine, thanks), however I understand that VS serializes data within the project.

The error message relates to AppData.Globals. Both the UserControls have the following declarations in them:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
[NonSerialized]
private AppData.Globals _g;
```

AppData.Globals itself is declared thus:

```
namespace AppData
{
    public class Globals : Dolphin.Globals
    {
        private AppData.Servers _servers;
        private AppData.DataTypes _dataTypes;
        private AppData.SqlTypes _sqlTypes;
        private AppData.CtrlTypes _ctrlTypes;
        private ImageList _imageList;
        ...
```

AppData.Globals is only used at runtime and doesn't need to be serialized by the designer. I'm using VS2012 still. Please help - I'm losing my hair over this.

**Update**: I've managed to delete out the instance of DateTimeExpEditor from within CtrlTypePropsEditorDateBox by editing the designer file directly using notepad. If I now try and create a new one, I get this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand why, but having deleted and recreated DateTimeExpEditor a couple of times, error messages pointed to the properties ValueDateTime and ValueExpression on the control. I modified them to include the following compiler directives:

```
        [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public DateTime ValueDateTime
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTime.Parse(txt.Text);
            }
            set
            {
                txt.Text = value.ToString(_format);
            }
        }


        [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public Expression ValueExpression
        {
            get
            {
                return new Expression(_g, "DATETIME", enumExpressionSource.Expression, txt.Text);
            }
            set
            {
                txt.Text = value.ToString();
            }
        }
```